# CLI only Linux on Intel Celeron 266 MHz

Tags: small-distribution, lightweight

I want to install a CLI only Linux system on an old desktop computer for testing and development purposes. It's an Intel Celeron 266MHz with 64 MB of RAM and 4 GB of HDD, and it doesn't reach the minimum requirements for Ubuntu Server.

Is there any other Linux distribution that would install with these specifications?

Comment: Since you're initially after an Ubuntu installation, Debian might be a good choice for a server. You definitely have sufficient resources for the installation. If the server is usable, however, depends on the applications and services you intend to run.

Comment: If you want an always-on server, buy a Raspberry Pi instead. Check your electricity bill and calculate how many months (or days) it will take for the cost of this old PC's electric consumption to overtake the cost of buying the RPi. If you want a test server, run a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is [something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Small_Linux) that might help you out.

> DSL supports only x86 PCs. The minimum system requirements are a 486
>   processor and 8 MB of RAM. DSL has been demonstrated browsing the web
>   with Dillo, running simple games and playing music on systems with a
>   486 processor and 16 MB of RAM. The system requirements are higher for
>   running Mozilla Firefox and optional add-ons such as the
>   OpenOffice.org office suite. It is often used in virtual machines due
>   to its small size and modest RAM requirements.

You can refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_Linux#Distributions_described_as_lightweight) link for more distributions that might suit your requirements.